# Multiprocessing with Python and instance methods

Tags: python, multiprocessing, scikit-learn

I'm using `scikit-learn` to train a `KernelDensity` with some "advanced" parameters. When evaluating `score_samples` after an initial fit, the processing takes a long time, and having multiple cores available I was hoping to get some speed improvements. `score_samples` (taking any length of a sample vector) should be simple to parallelize.

Until now, I tried `multiprocessing` to get things working. If I run my script (I'm using `Pool.map()`) I get the error that an instance method is not pickleable.

This is quite obvious, but using sklearn and relying heavily on instance methods, I can't change this behavoiur.

Is there any way to have any sort of multiprocessing that works with sklearn (and instance methods)? I don't mind if python copies the entire memory belonging to the main process (that's manageable) or if I need to submit each block to `score_samples` from a master program (not elegant, but would do the job).

Any suggestions where I should look?

Comment: I'm not familiar with working with scikit but are you attempting to store thread specific information and is why you were using a processing pool?

Comment: I'm author of a serializer (called `dill`) that can pickle instance methods.  I'm also author or a fork of multiprocessing (called `multiprocess`) that uses `dill`.  So, if scikit-learn can use either of those, then you should be able to do what you want.  If that's a "no-go", then if you can put your instance in a different file from the `Pool`, and `multiprocessing` should be able to handle it by serializing a reference to the method's namespace.

Comment: Found some other references to dill, that could work. Will try this as soon as possible. @Obj3ctiv3_C_88: No thread specific information needs to be stored and a processing pool seemed like a good idea. Not a requirement though.

Comment: It seems now python3 does support `Pool.map(self.method, args)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to guess you're needing to store thread specific state and is why you were wanting to create a processing pool. I'm not sure if this will work with scikit but I'd use threading.local(). It sounds like you're pretty familiar with Python but here is a link https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-local-data if it helps any.

I took a look at sci-kit and there docs. Have you tried using joblib/joblib.parallel?

Comment: No, that's not what I need. Maybe I was unspecific with my question, but storing thread local values is not (absolutely) necessary.

Comment: @Maaatt Updated answer, let me know if it needs a little clarification.

Comment: Hello joblib by itself  didn't improve much unfortunately. With everything people mentioned, I ended up a) upgrading to python3.5, using dill (awesome!) and migrating the whole analysis stuff (code and data) to a linux box and using fork. I probably reinvented the wheel, but at least it's working. Problem solved... :-)